# Why can't "had better" take a that-clause?

Tags: grammaticality, idioms

Given that we say things such as "I'd rather (that) you do it.", I'd expect "I had better (that) you do it." to be possible as well to mean "I would consider/find/have it better that you do it.", analogous to "I would consider/find/have it rather that you do it." (*rather* being the comparative of the archaic *rathe*).

However, a quick search would show that this isn't used and is likely ungrammatical. Is there any reason behind this?

Comment: The contraction _I'd rather_ is short for _I **would** rather_, not _had_. You used to be able to say _I would better (that) `S`_, but not for several hundred years. Anyway, _would rather_ is an idiomatic paraphrase for _prefer_, and _had better_ is an idiomatic paraphrase for _should_. As idioms, they are not compositional, and don't follow whatever rules you expect. Idioms make their own rules; they're frozen, like individual words.

Comment: Well, it's still good to know that _I would better (that) `S`_ used to be possible. What may be idiom now might once have been governed by rules before. This question was a probe in that direction, however impractical it may be to analyze idioms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is because. I'm sorry, but that's all there is to it. *Had better* takes an infinitive without *to*, not a *that* clause. It's possible to explain the historical process by which this happened, but not to explain *why* it happened that way.

By the way "I would have(/find/consider) it rather" is not idiomatic English either: "I would rather have it that ... " is idiomatic.